# how to read files from directory

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdocumentdirectory

i got a project that someone else write.
the project saves video file in this path,`file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/CAC8F2CB-1C7D-4805-BF1A-42B63B258E95/Documents/output.mp4`

i want to play the file with MPMoviePlayerController, how can i access the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firslty load the path and file URL:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *localFilePath = [photoDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
```

Then load up MPMoviePlayerController with the URL

```
- (void)initMoviePlayer 
{
didExit = NO;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:mMoviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];

NSLog(@"initMoviePlayer: %@ ",[self getMovieURL]);

mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self getMovieURL]];

mMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

mMoviePlayer.view.hidden = YES;

[mMoviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

mMoviePlayer.view.frame = [self.view bounds];

mMoviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;

[[self view] addSubview:[mMoviePlayer view]];

[mMoviePlayer play];

}

- (void) moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

// start playing the movie

    mMoviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;

    animateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(playMovie:) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:NO];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{        

}
```

Comment: not working i am getting i am getting an error
errorLog MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
```

Here in `fullPath` you will have path you mentioned above.

For more detail on how to play video, refer [this tutorial](http://www.imedian.net/en/2012/03/video-for-iphoneipad-using-mpmovieplayercontroller/)

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Actually I had integer variable for playing many video's, anyways edited answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code mate,

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *videoFilePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoFilePath];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the above URL somewhere

```
NSString *fullURL = @"/var/mobile/Applications/CAC8F2CB-1C7D-4805-BF1A-42B63B258E95/Documents/output.mp4"
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: isDirectory:YES]; //If YES not works use NO
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
```

Hope that helps